# How to pass all arrays into formArray maatwebsite-laravel-excel

Tags: arrays, laravel, foreach, laravel-excel

im getting all the array what i need. but when i don't know how to pass all the arrayes

```
$data = array('JOB NO','INVOICE NO','CUSTOMER','VAT(OUT PUT)','ACTUAL VAT');
                foreach($jobs  as $row){
                    $client =$row->company->name;
                    if($row->company->name != "PSL"){
                        $client = $row->job->customer_name;
                    }
                    $data1[]=array($row->job_no,$row->invoice_no,$client,number_format(($row->amount)*15/115,2,'.',','));
                }

              // dd($data1);
                $data3 = array($data,$data1[0]);
                $sheet->fromArray($data3,null,'A5',false,false);
```

when i check here like this `$data3 = array($data,$data1[0]);` im getting  one row in my Excel i don't know how to pass all the array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do.

```
// Array that will be used to generate the sheet
$sheetArray = array();

// Add the headers
$sheetArray[] = array('JOB NO','INVOICE NO','CUSTOMER','VAT(OUT PUT)','ACTUAL VAT');

// Add space between headers and results if needed
$sheetArray[] = array(); // Add an empty row
$sheetArray[] = array(); // Add an empty row

// Add the results
foreach($jobs  as $row){
    $client = $row->company->name;
    if($row->company->name != "PSL"){
        $client = $row->job->customer_name;
    }
    $sheetArray[] = array($row->job_no,$row->invoice_no,$client,number_format(($row->amount)*15/115,2,'.',','));
}

// Generating the sheet from the array
$sheet->fromArray($sheetArray);
```